# Cumulative sum of multiple object attributes in a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of object sorted on a month-year `String` attribute.

My object class defination looks like:

```java
public class Obj {
    String year;
    Long membercount;
    Long nonmembercount;
    Double memberpayment;
    Double nonmemberpayment;
}
```

```
new Obj("9-2015",100,20,10,5),
new Obj("10-2015",220,40,20,55),
new Obj("11-2015",300,60,30,45),
new Obj("12-2015",330,30,50,6),
new Obj("1-2016",100,10,10,4)
)
```

I want to do cumulative sum on `membercount`, `nonmembercount`, `memberpayment`, and `nonmemberpayment`.

So my new `List` of objects would be like below:

```
new Obj("9-2015",100,20,10,5)
new Obj("10-2015",320,60,30,60)
new Obj("11-2015",620,120,60,105)
new Obj("12-2015",950,150,110,111)
new Obj("1-2016",1050,160,120,115)
```

I tried with `Collectors.summingDouble` but it gives me all sum not cumulative.

I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You can't stream raw JSON. Does this represent some class? What does the class look like?

Comment: @shmosel yes it represent POJO class. Just for better clarity I have shown as json

Comment: The JSON obfuscates instead of clarifying. Please post the actual class definition.

Comment: Still no class definition.

Comment: And what about simple create a method in this Object that will do the first sum (of the 4 variable). Then in your stream, you just need to do the sum of the result of this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct support for cumulative operations in the Stream API, though it would be possible to implement such an operation via a custom `Collector`. But it’s worth noting that there is already a direct support for such operations on arrays, which might be sufficient for your case:

Extending you sketch of `Obj` to

```
public class Obj {
    String year;
    Long membercount;
    Long nonmembercount;
    Double memberpayment;
    Double nonmemberpayment;

    public Obj(String year, long membercount, long nonmembercount,
            double memberpayment, double nonmemberpayment) {
        this.year = year;
        this.membercount = membercount;
        this.nonmembercount = nonmembercount;
        this.memberpayment = memberpayment;
        this.nonmemberpayment = nonmemberpayment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Obj("+year+", "+membercount+", "+nonmembercount
            +", "+memberpayment+", "+nonmemberpayment+')';
    }
}
```

the solution can look like:

```
// test data
List<Obj> list=Arrays.asList(
    new Obj("9-2015", 100, 20, 10, 5),
    new Obj("10-2015", 220, 40, 20, 55),
    new Obj("11-2015", 300, 60, 30, 45),
    new Obj("12-2015", 330, 30, 50, 6),
    new Obj("1-2016", 100, 10, 10, 4));

// creating an array as need for the operation, it will contain the
// result afterwards, whereas the source list is not modified
Obj[] array = list.toArray(new Obj[0]);

// the actual operation
Arrays.parallelPrefix(array, (a,b) -> new Obj(b.year,
    a.membercount + b.membercount,
    a.nonmembercount + b.nonmembercount,
    a.memberpayment + b.memberpayment,
    a.nonmemberpayment + b.nonmemberpayment
));

// just print the result
Arrays.asList(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

the last line will print

```
Obj(9-2015, 100, 20, 10.0, 5.0)
Obj(10-2015, 320, 60, 30.0, 60.0)
Obj(11-2015, 620, 120, 60.0, 105.0)
Obj(12-2015, 950, 150, 110.0, 111.0)
Obj(1-2016, 1050, 160, 120.0, 115.0)
```

While this operation is unlikely to benefit from parallel processing for this small number of elements, there is unfortunately no sequential version of this operation. So you might consider using an ordinary loop solution instead…

---

For completeness, here is a Stream Collector based solution for cumulative operations. Like with `Arrays.parallelPrefix`, the update function must be side-effect-free and associative, which is the case for a function returning a new object with summed up properties.

```
public static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> cumulative(BinaryOperator<T> update) {
    return Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
        (l,o) -> {
            if(!l.isEmpty()) o=update.apply(l.get(l.size()-1), o);
            l.add(o);
        },
        (l,m) -> {
            if(l.isEmpty()) return m;
            if(!m.isEmpty()) {
                T a = l.get(l.size()-1);
                for(T b: m) l.add(update.apply(a, b));
            }
            return l;
        });
}
```

using it with the setup as above:

```
List<Obj> result = list.stream().collect(cumulative((a,b) -> new Obj(b.year,
    a.membercount + b.membercount,
    a.nonmembercount + b.nonmembercount,
    a.memberpayment + b.memberpayment,
    a.nonmemberpayment + b.nonmemberpayment
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, this is what I was able to come up with.

I used `map(o->o.membercount)` and `collect(Collectors.summingDouble(n->n))` to do the calculation for each field. Take a look.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DoubleSummation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Obj> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Obj("9-2015",100,20,10,5));
        list.add(new Obj("10-2015",220,40,20,55));
        list.add(new Obj("11-2015",300,60,30,45));
        list.add(new Obj("12-2015",330,30,50,6));
        list.add(new Obj("1-2016",100,10,10,4));

        Double sumMemberCount = list.stream().mapToDouble(o->o.membercount).sum();
        Double sumNonmembercount = list.stream().mapToDouble(o->o.nonmembercount).sum();
        Double sumMemberpayment = list.stream().mapToDouble(o->o.memberpayment).sum();
        Double sumNonmemberpayment = list.stream().mapToDouble(o->o.nonmemberpayment).sum();

        System.out.println(sumMemberCount);
        System.out.println(sumNonmembercount);
        System.out.println(sumMemberpayment);
        System.out.println(sumNonmemberpayment);
    }
}

class Obj{

    String year;
    long membercount;
    long nonmembercount;
    double memberpayment;
    double nonmemberpayment;

    public Obj(String year, long membercount, long nonmembercount, double memberpayment, double nonmemberpayment) {
        this.year = year;
        this.membercount = membercount;
        this.nonmembercount = nonmembercount;
        this.memberpayment = memberpayment;
        this.nonmemberpayment = nonmemberpayment;
    }

}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: It’s really strange to see a `map` to a `double`, followed by `Collectors.summingDouble`, now requiring an identity function. Why not use the mapping function directly in the collector, i.e. `list.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(o->o.field))`? Besides, it’s also worth thinking about `list.stream().mapToDouble(o->o.field).sum()` instead and changing the type of the result variables to `double` too. But your solution calculates the sum rather than the cumulative sum anyway…

Comment: @Holger yes you are correct I am getting sum not cumulative .Appreciate your help in this

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
List<Obj> objects = ...;
int cumulSum[] = {0};

objects.stream().map(obj -> {
    cumulSum[0] += obj.membercount;
    return new Obj(obj.year, cumulSum[0], ...);
});
```

Comment: I want cumulative sum and not sum of all attributes. Really appreciate for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature, which adds built-in support for this sort of cumulative accumulation:

```java
List<Obj> summed = list.stream()
        .gather(Gatherers.scan(
                () -> new Obj("", 0, 0, 0, 0),
                (o1, o2) -> new Obj(
                        o2.year,
                        o1.membercount + o2.membercount,
                        o1.nonmembercount + o2.nonmembercount,
                        o1.memberpayment + o2.memberpayment,
                        o1.nonmemberpayment + o2.nonmemberpayment
                )))
        .toList();
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.scan`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#scan(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiFunction)) gatherer to convert the initial stream to a stream of cumulative sums.

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.scan`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#scan(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiFunction))

> Returns a Gatherer that performs a Prefix Scan -- an incremental accumulation -- using the provided functions. Starting with an initial value obtained from the `Supplier`, each subsequent value is obtained by applying the `BiFunction` to the current value and the next input element, after which the resulting value is produced downstream.
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: ["1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345", "123456", "1234567", "12345678", "123456789"]
> List<String> numberStrings =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
>           .gather(
>               Gatherers.scan(() -> "", (string, number) -> string + number)
>            )
>           .toList();
> ```